# Spring IOC inherited bean contains two instance fields of same name

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I have a class "A" which contains protected filed "dao" and public setter method. No problem in initiating this bean through setter injection by referring "dao" bean.

I have another class called "B" which extends class "A". In bean definition, i am referring bean "a" using "parent" attribute. But when try to use bean "b", getting null pointer exception. When I try to debug, it displays two instance fields of same name(dao), with one field is populated and another is null. I am using `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` to manage transactions. Is it because of proxy issue?

[image]

Comment: Add your code for the classes it concerns.

Comment: You very probably have a sub type that hides an instance variable from a parent type.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis is correct. Interfacing application jar file had pathetic implementation with same name and package.